# Create custom Gridview with images of variable width and height

Tags: android, gridview

I want to create Grid view like Google plus which arranges images in variable width and height in the layout. For example say i have 7 images, and these images should be arranged in the grid view( Not in regular grid view but with variable rows and columns). These images should change their position in grid view after sometime say 5 seconds.

Comment: It's great that you want this, what have you tried in order achieve it?

Comment: I'm new to android and i checked on normal grid views and also i checked GIT Repositories available similar to what i have asked.. https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView https://github.com/chrisjenx/StaggeredGridView

Comment: Try this library... It works good https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid